# Discount Coupons for Users

Tags: wordpress

I am running WordPress, I have 250 products on my web page, I want to allow a discount to certain User across all products, what is easiest way to do this in word press please

Comment: Add a flag to a user profile, if it's set, they get the bonus. You can extend user profiles in various ways, including plugins like ACF and Pods.

Comment: cool and thanks - I will try it, is there a tutorial on this you can point me to

Comment: Both mentioned plugins have a good documentation and support forums.